# How to set library path for java outlook connector moyocore.dll in jsf project

Tags: java, email, jsf, outlook, connector

I have a problem setting the library path for moyocore.dll in my jsf project, i have already tried to allocate the file in different folders and set different paths.

```
Outlook.setLibraryPath("C:\\Users\\irebollo\\Desktop\\plazos\\Java Outlook Connector\\lib\\moyocore.dll");
```

this one was working in a single java file, but when added the code to a bean function in my jsf project absolute route stops working, ok that was obvious but the problem is next

then I tried setting relative paths from my workspace like:

```
Outlook.setLibraryPath("\\lib-joc\\moyocore.dll");
Outlook.setLibraryPath("\\resources\\lib-joc\\moyocore.dll");
```

tried with "\" and "/" but still cant get it working.

I have to say that everything in the code is ok, the only problem is the path to the library but if someone needs to see the code i will post it.

moyocore.dll is allocated in /projectRoot/plazosExcel/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
also in /projectRoot/web/resources/lib-joc/moyocore.dll

I'm not very skilled with JSF and it's folder structure so maybe i'm not putting it in the right place or not referencing it ok or both.

Additional information:

Path to workspace -> C:\Users\irebollo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\plazosExcel

OS -> Win7

IDE -> NetBeans8

I have googled it but there is no information about java outlook connector in jsf so I hope this big community can help me once again.

P.S: it's my first question so if i'm missing something or there is something wrong i'd appreciate to know it.

Comment: not really sure, but I'd try to place «moyocore.dll», «moyocore.jar» and «joc-v3.0.4-eval.jar» all under WEB-INF/lib and use Outlook.setLibraryPath("moyocore.dll");

Comment: thanks for the quick reply Leo. They are already placed there, but it doesn't work with Outlook.setLibraryPath("moyocore.dll");

Comment: what about the absolute path?

Comment: as far as i know absolute paths dont work if your application runs under tomcat. if the absolute path worked i wouldn`t be asking this question because it should work properly when i ran it for first time.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was just trying to narrow the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, after adding the library to the windows PATH var and try tons of different locations i added this to the JVM options:

(included moyocore.dll in C:\lib previously)

-Djava.library.path="C:\lib"

That was yesterday, 10 mins ago I realized that JVM options dont need "" so i changed it and started to work.

Conclusion: I'm stupid, but I hope my struggle with JSF and JOC may be helpful for someone.

This question is over, can be closed or archived.